# Ios Encryption.?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdk

I want to decrypt/encrypt file using AES-256 on iOS. Does anyone know anything about CCCrypt and CommonCrypto APIs or samples that I can look.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone: How to encrypt a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235171/iphone-how-to-encrypt-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

Am using this solution ... hope it helps

https://github.com/dev5tec/FBEncryptor

regards,

Jorge.